# Let Ionic2 browser apply windows(wp) theme

Tags: ionic-framework, win-universal-app

I am using Ionic v2(currectly is 2.0.0-beta.25).
After created a Ionic v2 project, and run the

```
ionic serve
```

command, Ionic will apply the iOS theme in the browser by default. Since Ionic announced it supported the windows platform, i am planning to use ionic v2 to create an application, so i wish i can preview as windows/wp theme in my browser. [The document](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/developer-tips/) said that add `?ionicplatform=android` to the URL can change how Ionic sees which platform i am on, it works and changed the theme as android. Then i tried `?ionicplatform=wp` and also `?ionicplatform=windows` . it doesn't work.

I also followed [this document](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/platform-specific-styles/) to add `class="wp"` , it still doesn't work. i also found Ionic Lab, this application even don't have a windows phone option.

The offical document have a live perview on the right side of the v2 components document page. so i think maybe there is some way to make the perview in browser to apply the windows/wp theme. I've google it but can't find any answer.

I also tryed edit my UserAgent as Lumia phone but it still doesn't works.

So, if i want the `ionic serve` browser perview apply windows/wp theme, what should i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using chrome. When project are running make inspect and select `ctrl+shift+m` for change to device mode and choice your phone. If windows phone are not in that list, click edit in dropdown and there you have at least one Windows Phone. :)

Comment: I've tryed this and it doesn't work. whatever which device i choose it will always display a iOS theme except i append ` ?ionicplatform=android ` to the URL (then it will apply the Material Design theme). but all i want is let it apply a WinPhone theme :(